# Java exit code -1073740791

Tags: java, javafx, gradle, libgdx

Столкнулся с проблемой, при компиляции приложения libgdx, приложение не открывает окно, а завершается с сообщением `Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)`
Пробовал создать новый проект (пустой) утилитой libgdx, результат тот же. Так же стал себя вести проект javafx собранный gradle. Переустановка ide, gradle не помогла.
Что могло привести к такому поведению ? И как это исправить?
Upd: проблема запуска из .class, потому что созданный из этого же проекта jar запускает окно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опытным путем найден виновник, это драйвер nvidia версии 378.49. Ставится в win10 в фоне и по этому незаметен.

Comment: Надо было ставить Linux

Comment: В виду специфики работы нет возможности перейти на линукс ( софта нет необходимого, а работать через вайн не вариант)